# Using iOS Swift & Android Libraries that rely on Bluetooth Low Energy with Gluon-Mobile

Tags: android, ios, gluon, gluon-mobile

Can Gluon-Mobile use libraries written for iOS in Swift that have iOS Bluetooth Low Energy function calls? 
Library in question: https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/IOS-Pods-DFU-Library

And Android Java libraries that have Android Bluetooth Low Energy Calls? 
Library in question: https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-DFU-Library

These libraries handle device firmware updates over Bluetooth Low Energy for devices running on nRF5x SoCs

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Wrap the native calls in Java using JNI. 
There is an example Logging wrapper somewhere in either Gluon Samples or on GluonHQ.com.

Comment: Yawn yawn yawn yes please yawn

Comment: Will attempt to the use this with the libraries